# Django refresh page without reload whole page

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I want to refresh the page at certain intervals, for example, every 10 seconds, without reloading the page. I'm sending get request to api. My ajax codes refreshes the page well but it's causing problems because it loads all the divs again and again. How can I make the div-focused refresh delete the same previous div when refreshing?

hmtl;

```
{% extends 'elements/sidebar.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<!---->
<img src="{% static '/images/techops.png' %}" alt="" class="responsive">
<div class="p text-center bg-light"> 
</div>
<br>
<div class="containerdashcontrol" style="float: top; margin-bottom: 2%;">
  <div class="dashbaslik" style="text-align: center;"> <span style="font-size: 30px; color: white;">DASHBOARD CHECK</span></div>
  <form class="form-horizontal" action="dashcontrol" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% load humanize %}
                   <!---->   
  </form> 
  </div>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <section class="pricing-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
            <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-6 col-md-8">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Pricing Table starts -->
        <div id="testdiv" class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
          {%if testtt > 1000 %}<div class="dashcontrol2 featured">{%else%}<div class="dashcontrol featured">{%endif%}
          <h4>{%if testtt > 1000 %}<span style="color: red;">XX</span><box-icon type='solid' name='badge' color="red"></box-icon>{%else%}<span style="color: green;">XX</span><box-icon type='solid' name='badge-check' color="green"></box-icon>{%endif%} </box-icon></h4>
          <h4>{{testtt|intcomma}}</h4>
         <a target="_blank" href="XX"><h6>KIBANA</h6></a>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
</section>
            </div>
    <script>
       setInterval(function() { 
      $.get("/dashcontrol", function(data, status){ 
        $("#testdiv").hide(); //hide the page
        $("#testdiv").append(data); // and after you hide that data append it.
    });  
}, 5000);
    </script>
    {% endblock content %}
    {% block scripts %}
  
    {% endblock scripts %}
```

url.py;

```
url(r'^dashcontrol$', views.dashcontrol, name='dashcontrol'),
```

ajax;

```
<script>
          
    setInterval(function() { 
      $.get("/dashcontrol", function(data, status){ 
        $("body").html(data); 
    });  
}, 15000);
    </script>
```

view;

```
def dashcontrol(request):
        url = "http://XX/XX*/_search"
        headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
        params = {XX}
        print('OK')
        response = requests.get(url=url, json=params, headers=headers)
        data = response.json()
        testtt = data['hits']['total']
        print(data['hits']['total'])
        print('OK')
        return render(request, 'dashcontrol.html', {'testtt ':testtt }
```

Comment: share your dashcontrol view and his template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one of the possible solution for this is 
hide default duration is 400ms and i do not think the user will notice that.
create new url

```
url(r'^dashcontrol$', views.dashcontrol, name='dashcontrol'),
url(r'^updatadashcontrol$', views.updatedashcontrol, name='updatedashcontrol'),
```

js

```
<script>
          
    setInterval(function() { 
      $.get("{% url 'updatedashcontrol' %}", function(data, status){ 
        $("#testdiv").empty(); //hide the page
        $("#testdiv").append(data); // and after you hide that data append it.
    });  
}, 15000);
    </script>
```

views.py

```
def dashcontrol(request):
        url = "http://XX/XX*/_search"
        headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
        params = {XX}
        print('OK')
        response = requests.get(url=url, json=params, headers=headers)
        data = response.json()
        testtt = data['hits']['total']
        print(data['hits']['total'])
        print('OK')
        return render(request, 'dashcontrol.html', {'testtt ':testtt }

def updatedashcontrol(request):
        url = "http://XX/XX*/_search"
        headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
        params = {XX}
        print('OK')
        response = requests.get(url=url, json=params, headers=headers)
        data = response.json()
        testtt = data['hits']['total']
        print(data['hits']['total'])
        print('OK')
        return render(request, 'partialdashcontrol.html', {'testtt ':testtt }
```

partialdashcontrol.html(just this do not add body or html)

```
<div class="col-md-4">
          {%if testtt > 1000 %}<div class="dashcontrol2 featured">{%else%}<div class="dashcontrol featured">{%endif%}
          <h4>{%if testtt > 1000 %}<span style="color: red;">XX</span><box-icon type='solid' name='badge' color="red"></box-icon>{%else%}<span style="color: green;">XX</span><box-icon type='solid' name='badge-check' 

    color="green"></box-icon>{%endif%} </box-icon></h4>
              <h4>{{testtt|intcomma}}</h4>
             <a target="_blank" href="XX"><h6>KIBANA</h6></a>
            </ul>
           </div>
```

Comment: its not worked :(

Comment: what error did you get ?

Comment: @altintash what is inside your dashboard.html update your answer and share it.

Comment: i can see it is throwing get request again in terminal but it is not refreshing the page

Comment: @altintash could you pease share the current page where you applying this ajax not the function called ?

Comment: a page of copies of the div I'm posting, its refreshing but after hide div not reloading div again.

Comment: @altintash let us continue this discussion in the chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239526/help-in-js-and-django

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for the room :(

Comment: @altintash i see.what is your current page where you have <script>...</script> i think you are not in the dashcontrol.html template?

Comment: @altintash this will not work but let me try something

Comment: Can't we do the refresh based on div because I want to update some information in the modal?

Comment: its worked but clonning the body https://i.ibb.co/F0sq7H0/image.png

Comment: @altintash did you add the body or html tag inside the updatedashcontrol.html ?

Comment: its perfectly worked!! thank u so much i do a mistake of return render html part, thank u so much

Comment: hi again :) If my request is not too much :) How can I make ajax active and passive with the switch?

 <div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Checked switch checkbox input</label>
</div>